# Android Studio breaks a part package into seperate directories

Tags: android-studio, directory, package

I recently imported a project I have been working on from eclipse to android studio and have been using robolectric to test units of my code. The unit tests are placed in a file system similar to this: src/test/java/com.foo.bar where com.foo.bar is a package. On every reboot of Android Studio the file system breaks a part the directory into src/test/java/com/foo/bar where all of the folders are directories (including the java folder which should be a Java folder).

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Okay so I figured it out! What I did was create a new Java folder and place it into src/test which resolved the package issue. I then had some build issues with gradle which involved not being able to locate some imports I was using for testing, such as JUnit and Robolectric. This was resolved by declaring two different sourceSets, one for main and one for robolectric in the build.gradle file.

Comment: This post helped me with defining the sourceSets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457363/integrating-roboelectric-with-android-studio-with-gradle-always-gives-package-or